# How to disable captive portal detection on Android 6.0?

Tags: android, captiveportal

Before, I just execute the command in terminal:

```
settings put global captive_portal_server 127.0.0.1 && settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

And everything worked fine. But now the captive portal window "Join Wifi" appears again, giving error:

> Not Found for page 127.0.0.1/generate_204.

I use Samsung Galaxy A5 2016 Android 6, if it matters. How to disable this terrible awful detection?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, use `settings put global captive_portal_mode 0`.

From https://www.kuketz-blog.de/android-captive-portal-check-aenderung/ (using myself to force my Android to use the WiFi for establishing a VPN tunnel using strongswan through a company network forcing the use of a proxy).